# Difference between SparseArray Vs ArrayList?

Tags: java, android

I want to know performance and efficiency of `SparseArray` and `ArrayList` and which one is better to use.
I can't understand when to use `SparseArray` and when `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The purpose of a `SparseArray` is to save memory if you have a list that has lots of gaps in. If you only have 10 items, and the numbers that index them range from 0 to 1000, then an `ArrayList` will have lots of `null` entries in it, and that will be quite wasteful. A `SparseArray` will use data structures internally to avoid that problem.

The alternative in this situation is a `HashMap`, which is better than a `SparseArray` if you have lots of items.

> The implementation is not intended to be appropriate for data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups require a binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting entries in the array. For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

From the [Android dev documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html).

Comment: [Here's a good article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/android-performance-tweaking-parsearray.html) that compares performance of `SparseArray` and `HashMap`.

Comment: But `BinarySearch` is faster I guess O o

Answer (score 3):

SparseList implements a `SparseArray`. This class is identical to `java.util.ArrayList`, except that the former permits assignment to array indexes that are beyond the current length of the list, using the expected `set()` and `add()` methods.*

I think here there is all you need to know to understand which one to use.

SparseList is also more efficient

more info [here](http://software.clapper.org/javautil/api/org/clapper/util/misc/SparseArrayList.html)