# In Java, when would i use ArrayList over a sparseArray?

Tags: java, arraylist, sparse-matrix

Is there any advantage to using an ArrayList over a sparseArray.  A sparseArray is better memory management has it does not put nulls in empty slots like ArrayList will.  But Would you always recommend me to use a sparseArray over an ArrayList which is used very commonly ?

To be clear, i am not asking about what is a sparseArray (i have already defined it above), i am asking When would one want to use an ArrayList over a sparseArray.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25444226/difference-between-sparsearray-vs-arraylist explains it.

Comment: please read my question ? i am asking when would an ArrayList be more beneficial then a sparseArray, that link is for difference between sparseArray.

Comment: I didn't downvote, and please don't ask people to remove votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the list is *not* sparse, an ArrayList requires less memory than SparseArray, and accesses by index in O(1) rather than O(log n).

From the [SparseArray class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseArray.html):

> Note that this container keeps its mappings in an array data structure, using a binary search to find keys. The implementation is not intended to be appropriate for data structures that may contain large numbers of items. It is generally slower than a traditional HashMap, since lookups require a binary search and adds and removes require inserting and deleting entries in the array. For containers holding up to hundreds of items, the performance difference is not significant, less than 50%.

Comment: I think im understanding now. So if i have a list that i know ahead of time will have lots of gaps in the slots, then i would use a sparseArray. If i know there are minimal amount of empty slots i can use ArrayList, correct ?

Comment: Also, when you say "not sparse" you mean hardly any empty slots, right ?

Comment: A sparse array has more empty slots than non-empty. If you have few if any empty slots, the choice of ArrayList is clear. If the array is sparse, you *might* want a SparseArray, depending on whether the proportion of potentially empty slots and your requirements merits the trade-off of slower access for less memory. In some cases, you might want to represent a sparse array with an ArrayList, when the faster access is more important to you than the extra memory.